# Array Reduce in javascript starts returning NaN after the first sum

Tags: javascript, arrays

I cant figure out why array.reduce will return the correct sum on the first pass, but returns NaN on the next passes. Can anyone shed some light as to why this is happening?

Edit - i need to explain, im trying to have a new array with each one adding to the previous value. so

[1, 2, 3, 4]
becomes
[1, 3, 6, 10]

Right now it comes out 
[1,3,nan,nan]

Working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/env4c02b/1/

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 6, 4];

function getSum(total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr) {
     var newVal = Number(total) + Number(currentValue)
   total.push(newVal);
   return total;
}

var display = numbers.reduce(getSum, [])
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = display
```

Comment: In `getSum` the variable `total` is an array of numbers. The code `Number(total)` results in `NaN`.

Comment: what are trying to achieve in this function ?

Comment: Ok, i thought total was the value of the previous - that is a good start thanks, i edited with more info.

Comment: `var total = 0, display = numbers.map(v => total += v);` just some food for thought

Comment: Wow thanks Thomas, that worked with much less code than using reduce. very very interesting! now i understand both much deeper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying with `Number(ARRAY)`? If you try to convert an array to a number, you will have a problem as is a non-sense conversion (like apples to a table). You want to get the last added number of the array and sum it:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function getSum(total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr) {
   var newVal = currentValue; // The new value is the current number
   if (currentIndex > 0) { // If we are in the second position or more, sum the last value, which is the curent position minus one.
       newVal += total[currentIndex-1];
   }
   total.push(newVal);
   return total;
}

var display = numbers.reduce(getSum, []);
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = display
```

Comment: Thanks! i am trying to digest your comment but i forgot to explain what im doing, i edited the post with more info. im trying to make a new array with the values from the previous total

Comment: @user3869231 Updated it :P

Comment: What a boss! Thanks :)

Comment: @user3869231 np :P